# replace to new fragment with FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a instance of `FragmentManager` (variable `frgManager`), I replace to new fragment by:

```
 // Fragments all use the same container
 frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, nextFragment, MyTag).commit();
```

Let's say I have three fragments `A, B, C`,

the app show fragments in the sequence of `A-->B-->C`. Everytime show next fragment, I call the code above.

**The problem is** after `C` is shown, I close `C`, then `B` is shown in foreground, but the `onResume()` of `A` is also called. **Why?** How to avoid that because I expect only `B`'s `onResume()` get called in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, nextFragment, MyTag).addToBackStack().commit();`

Use `addToBackStack` when creating all of your fragments. This way, only 1 can be active at once.